# 2020 Huffy Arlington Adult Trike clicking noise from rear axle in dual chain Trike

Tags: chain, rear-wheel, tricycle, clicking, skipping

While pedaling or spinning the left or right rear wheels there is a clicking sound like something is skipping. It comes from the right rear wheel area.
When spinning the left rear wheel the right rear wheel will also spin like positraction on a car.
There are four screws in the axle, but I don’t know what they are for.
The manual does not give me any information about them.
How do I fix the clicking noise?

Comment: To clarify - this trike is a solid beam rear axle so that both rear wheels are locked and spin together ?    A photo of the source of the clicking might help here too.

Comment: A video showing the problem and the layout of the transmission/drivetrain would be helpful, since adult trikes are put together a few different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all axle bearings I did and it stopped the clicking.

Comment: This might be the right solution but there are other possible issues. More information is needed before selecting this option